# Storing access token object in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

Hi all currently I am facing an issue while storing object of **OAuth::AccessToken**. First let me describe the situation.

I am working on rails 4 application and I am consuming / using API of another site say *example.com*, which uses 3-legged oauth authorization (same as [twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged)). To achieve this functionality I have used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519829/6306144) and implemented the same.

Now I am able to open communication channel between the *example.com* and my application also able use their API's.

Here is my sample implementation

**Create consumer**

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new API_KEY,
                               API_SECRET,
                               {
                                 site: SITE_URL,
                                 header: { ACCEPT_HEADERS },
                                 http_method: :get,
                                 request_token_url: request_token_uri,
                                 access_token_url: access_token_uri,
                                 authorize_url: authorizerequest_token_uri
                               }
```

**Fetching request token**

```
request_token = consumer.get_request_token({}, CALLBACK_URL)
```

**Goto to the authorize url and get the access token verifier'**

```
request_token.authorize_url
verifier = gets.chomp
```

**Fetch access tokene**

```
access_token = request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: verifier)
```

Now I am using this access_token (Object of OAuth::AccessToken) throughout the application. (For making get, post API calls). As I have to use in the application I have stored this object into the session.

```
session[:access_token] = access_token
```

But sometimes I am getting the ***cookie overflow error***. So I have a following queries.

- What is the good way to store this object? (other than DB).
- Should I have to implement middleware?
- Or is there any other way to achieve same type of functionality.

Comment: how many bytes long is the access token?

Comment: why don't you want to use the DB? You have to store this data somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same type of problem. I have stored access token in **database**, (I am using mysql database). For this, I have used [Marshal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html) class of ruby.

From the doc

> The marshaling library converts collections of Ruby objects into a
>   byte stream, allowing them to be stored outside the currently active
>   script. This data may subsequently be read and the original objects
>   reconstituted.

Here is my **sample code for storing the access token**

```
access_token = request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: verifier)
encrypt_access_token = Marshal.dump(access_token)
AccessTokenUser.create(user_id: 1, access_token: encrypt_access_token)
```

Retrieve stored acceess_token

```
decrypt_access_token = Marshal.load(access_token)
```

Then you can use this decrypted access token for making API call.

Comment: `Marshal` does NOT encrypt the access token. It simply converts it to a byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different session storage mechanism, for example memcached or redis (on the server). This may allow for a larger session. However, this is just "implementing a different type of database".

If you were brave or foolish, you could also try compressing the data or storing it directly in an encrypted cookie, or splitting into multiple chunks and storing in separate cookies, but all these are hacks and the best answer is to implement a db backend or upgrade your session storage. :)