# Store redirect url for later use in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I am working on rails 4 application and I am consuming / using API of another site say example.com, which uses 3-legged oauth authorization (same as twitter). To achieve this functionality I have used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516398/twitter-3-legged-authorization-in-ruby/16519829#16519829) and implemented the same.

Here is my implementation

**AuthController**

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :fetch_request_token, only: [:authorize]

  def authorize
    token = @consumer.get_request_token(oauth_callback: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/fetch_access_token')
    authorize_url = token.authorize_url
    redirect_to authorize_url
  end

  def fetch_access_token
    acc_token = request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: params[:oauth_verifier])
    # remaining logic
    redirect_to files_jds_path
  end

  private

  def fetch_request_token
    #logic for fetching request token
  end
end
```

**JDsController**

```
class JDsController < AuthController
  before_filter :authorize, only: [:files, :field_info] unless: :check_access_token

  def files
    # logic for the files
  end

  def field_info
    # logic for the files
  end

  private

  def check_access_token
    # logic for checking access_token
  end
end
```

Currently I am checking the access_token present or not before any action, if access_token not present, then I am fetching the access_token using authorize method.

If you see the `fetch_access_token` method from the `AuthController` (this is my callback url), where I have hard-coded redirect path as `files_jds_path`.

Because of this implementation though before_filter applied to the `field_info`, after fetching access_token it redirect to the `files_jds_path`.

But I need to make it generalized so that for any action it will redirect to the respective path.

Can anyone suggest how can I do this

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking.  You want to be able to send someone back to the original page they were looking for after being authorized?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you are using token based authentication and not sessions?

Comment: I am using session based authentication. The current implementation only links the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly set the OAuth callback url to include a path in a query parameter. Facebook and Twitter allow this.

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :fetch_request_token, only: [:authorize]

  def authorize

    uri = URI('http://localhost:3000/auth/fetch_access_token')
    uri.query = { redirect_to: params[:referrer] }.to_query if params[:referrer]


    token = @consumer.get_request_token(oauth_callback: uri)
    authorize_url = token.authorize_url
    redirect_to authorize_url
  end

    def fetch_access_token
       acc_token = request_token.get_access_token(
         oauth_verifier: params[:oauth_verifier]
       )
       # remaining logic
       redirect_to params[:referrer] || files_jds_path
   end
end
```

Comment: On a side note - I would do this by create an [OmniAuth strategy](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) for the OAuth provider instead.